# speed difference between using "out=" or not in 2 numpy functions (add/greater)

Tags: python, numpy

Recently I am trying to increase speed during my numpy operations, and I did some of the test below:

```
np.add(a,1,out=a)   # time=0.037
a=np.add(a,1)         # time=0.224
b=np.add(a,1)         # time=0.228
```

The 1st one using "out=" is about 5-8 times faster than the 2nd one and the 3rd one. I can understand the difference, because the 1st one did every add operation in their own place, while the 2nd and 3rd have to create new memory blocks.

Then I did some test with another function "greater":

```
np.greater(a,1,out=a)   # time=0.117
a=np.greater(a,1)         # time=0.138
b=np.greater(a,1)         # time=0.047
```

After several test, it seems that the 2nd one takes the most time, the 1st one takes about 80% time, and the 3rd one takes 30%-40% time.

I can not understand clearly about the "greater" function and its speed test result.
Please give some advice, Thank you very much!

```
import timeit

init = """
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(900000)
"""

f1="""
np.add(a,1,out=a)
"""

f2="""
a=np.add(a,1)
"""

f3="""
b=np.add(a,1)
"""

print(timeit.timeit(stmt=f1, setup=init,number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=f2, setup=init,number=100))
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=f3, setup=init,number=100))
```

Comment: What's the dtype in the `greater` examples?

Comment: @hpaulj    I am not sure about your "example". Does it mean numpy use manual? Or do you mean example in my post. In my code a.dtype=int32 and the result.dtype=bool.

Comment: `np.greater(a,1)` produces a boolean array.  But if `out=a`, that boolean is converted to `a.dtype`; in effect  `np.greater(a, 1).astype(int)`.

Comment: `np.cross` is one of the few `numpy` functions that I've seen that makes much use of the `out` parameter.  But in most cases the time savings are probably not worth the extra work and loss of clarity.  Don't focus on this to the point that you loose sight of more productive ways of improving your code.

Comment: @hpaulj   I think I got it! I forgot about the astype problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hpaulj  Thank you for the advice!  I am dealing with about 100,000,000 size array and I want to make sure it did not waste time creating new memory blocks. Anyway, before the time waste is noticable, I should focus on my overall code.